# Can't add dynamic values in MySQL table through PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I am trying to dynamically add values dynamically in my sample table. Here is the index.php code

```
  <body>  
       <div class="container">  
            <br />  
            <br />  
            <h2 align="center"></h2>  
            <div class="form-group">  
                 <form name="add_name" id="add_name">  
                      <div class="table-responsive">  
                           <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">  
                                <tr>  
                                     <td><input type="text" name="medname[]" placeholder="Medicine Name" class="form-control name_list" /></td> 
                                     <td><select name="frequency[]" class="form-control name_list"><option>24Hrs</option><option>8Hrs</option><option>12Hrs</option></select></td>
                                     <td><input name = "morningmed[]" type ="checkbox" class = "form-control name_list"/></td>
                                     <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>  
                                </tr>  
                           </table>  
                           <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />  
                      </div>  
                 </form>  
            </div>  
       </div>  
  </body>  

 <script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
  var i=1;  
  $('#add').click(function(){  
       i++;  
       $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text" name="medname[]" placeholder="Mediince Name" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><select name="frequency[]" class="form-control name_list"><option>24Hrs</option><option>8Hrs</option><option>12Hrs</option></select></td><td><input name = "morningmed[]" type ="checkbox" class = "form-control name_list"/></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');  
  });  
  $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
       var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
       $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
  });  
  $('#submit').click(function(){            
       $.ajax({  
            url:"name.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:$('#add_name').serialize(),  
            success:function(data)  
            {  
                 alert(data);  
                 $('#add_name')[0].reset();  
            }  
       });  
  });  
});  
</script>
```

Here is the code to insert data in table, name.php. At the moment im just inserting in one column, medname.

```
<?php  
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", " ","androidtest");  
 $medicineName =  $_POST["medname"];  
 var_dump($medicineName);

 $i=0;
 $countPatientMedName = count($medicineName);

 echo $countPatientMedName;

 while ($i < $countPatientMedName) {
 $medicineName = $medicineName[$i];

 $result=mysqli_query($connect,"insert into tbl_name (medname) Values       ('$medicineName')");


$i++;

}
?>
```

I inserted 'hello' and 'World', 2 rows were inserted, 'Hello' and 'e'. Cant understand why this is happening. Whatever I enter in the second row, its second letter is inserted in the database.

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: You are overwriting `$medicineName` (originally an array) with its first value. Then you are overwriting it (now a string) with its second letter. Use a different variable name.

Comment: Also, **SQL injection alert**. Use parameterised queries.

Comment: Yes, my bad. Thanks